# How to use an uncaught exception handler for a multi-thread test in junit?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I have the following code that I expect to run successfully to completion but the code fails at the line "fail("this should not be reached");".  Can someone please explain why the default uncaught exception handler is not called:

```
public class UncaughtExceptionTest extends TestCase
    implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private final List<Throwable> uncaughtExceptions =
        new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Throwable>();

    class UncaughtExceptionTestInnerClass implements Runnable {
        private final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor =
            new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        private final CountDownLatch latch;

        UncaughtExceptionTestInnerClass(CountDownLatch latch) {
            this.latch = latch;
            executor.schedule(this, 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("This is printed");
            fail("this should fail");
            latch.countDown();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testUncaughtExceptions() {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        UncaughtExceptionTestInnerClass testTheInnerClass =
                new UncaughtExceptionTestInnerClass(latch);
        try {
            if (!latch.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                if (uncaughtExceptions.size() > 0) {
                    Throwable exception = uncaughtExceptions.get(0);
                    System.out.println("First uncaught exception: " + 
                                    exception.getMessage());
                }
                else {
                    fail("this should not be reached");
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        uncaughtExceptions.add(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the `fail("this should fail");` line there? Is this intentional? This way the latch never counts down.

Comment: @BalusC: yes, this is intentional.  To pass the test correctly, the latch.await() method should time out, causing it to return false. The code should then print the message from the uncaught AssertionFailedError exception that was thrown on the line you are questioning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has to do with the fact you're using an **Executor** to run the task. The uncaught exception handler is invoked only if the thread is about to be terminated due to an uncaught exception. If you change your implementation to use a plain thread so that the thread will terminate with the exception, you will see the expected behavior.

Depending on how you submit tasks, the executor thread may catch all Throwables and handle them. Therefore, the thread does not terminate due to these exceptions, and thus the uncaught exception handler does not get involved. For example, **ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(Runnable)** will trigger the uncaught exception handler. However, **ThreadPoolExecutor.submit(Callable)** does not. Also, **ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule()** does not either (it has to do with their use of FutureTask  for implementation).

A better way of accessing unexpected exceptions with an executor service is via **Future**.

Answer (score 1):

`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule()` takes a `Runnable`/`Callable` argument, not `Thread`. The former don't have runtime exception handlers. Have a `try`/`catch` block for a `RuntimeException` in your `run` or `call` method.